# Pandas , From Dictionary to Pandas to plot Boolean

Tags: python, pandas

I am new Python programmer, 
and I want from this,

```
dic = {"word1": ["a","b","c"], "word2": ["b", "d", "e"], "word3": ["a", "f", "c"]}
```

to, this DataFrame Object.

[image]

I tried code like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=["a","b","c","d","e","f"], columns=[])
for i in result:
print("i",i)
print("v", v)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(i)
df.append(df2)
```

Please help me to how should I code this

Comment: sorry, I check now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First convert `dict` to `Series` and then use [MultiLabelBinarizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html) + `DataFrame` constructor, last cast to boolean:

```
d = {"word1": ["a","b","c"], "word2": ["b", "d", "e"], "word3": ["a", "f", "c"]}

s = pd.Series(d)
```

---

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()

df = pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(s),columns=mlb.classes_, index=s.index).astype(bool)
```

Another solution with [`str.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.join.html) for joining by `|` what is default separator in [`str.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html):

```
df = s.str.join('|').str.get_dummies().astype(bool)
```

---

```
print (df)
           a      b      c      d      e      f
word1   True   True   True  False  False  False
word2  False   True  False   True   True  False
word3   True  False   True  False  False   True
```

Comment: my hero too @YOSUKE

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way using `pd.get_dummies`:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {"word1": ["a","b","c"], "word2": ["b", "d", "e"], "word3": ["a", "f", "c"]}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index')
df['values'] = df.values.tolist()

df = df.drop(df.columns[:], 1)\
       .join(pd.get_dummies(df['values'].apply(pd.Series).stack()).sum(level=0))\
       .astype(bool)
```

**Result**

```
           a      b      c      d      e      f
word1   True   True   True  False  False  False
word2  False   True  False   True   True  False
word3   True  False   True  False  False   True
```

**Explanation**

- Create a `pd.Series` of lists for each word.
- Apply `pd.get_dummies` to this series with some manipulation.
- Convert type from `int` to `bool` for display purposes.

Comment: I wanted to choose you both as best answer but Mr. jezrael is a little bit faster,